# Modular multiplication, exponents, cycle length and gcd in a proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been reading a proof for quite some time now, I think I understood it but I am stuck in the following description ($\lambda$ is the cycle length of the powers of $a$) , $e \in {0, 1, 2, ... \lambda - 1}$ and $l(a)$ the cycle length of the powers of $a$:

> If $e$ is a positive integer then $(a^e)^f \equiv 1 \pmod p$ if and
> only if $e\cdot f$ is a multiple of $\lambda$.    This occurs only if
> $f$ is a multiple of $$\frac{\lambda}{\gcd(e, \lambda)}$$
>
> From this we find that:   $$l(a^e) = \frac{l(a)}{\gcd(e,\lambda)}$$

I don't understand how we determined what is the form of $f$. The $\frac{\lambda}{\gcd(e, \lambda)}$ reminds me the $lcm$ since $e\cdot \lambda = \gcd(e,\lambda) \cdot lcm(e,\lambda) \implies lcm = \frac{e\lambda}{gcd(e, \lambda)}$
but I am not sure if that is indeed relevant and how we ignore $e$ and get the last formula for $l(a^e)$.

Could someone please help me understand this?

Comment: Why is this question a duplicate? I don't understand

Comment: Well, the question being linked to *is* what your proof is proving.  But your question is about a particular point of the proof.

Comment: ... and Bill Dubuque's answer on the other post basically *is* this proof.

Comment: @fleablood: there is no way for me to have been able to figure out that the post is similar/relevant and be able to link that other answer with my specific question. After your answer, I think I can re-read the other post and may be, be able to understand it. In any case, my question was about **a specific statement** of a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems to be this basic number theory result:

> For integer $m,n,b$ if $mn$ is a multiple of $b$ then $m$ is a multiple of $\frac b{\gcd(b,n)}$ and $n$ is a multiple of $\frac b{\gcd(b,m)}$.

This very easy to verify.  If $mn$ is a multiple of $b$ then

$mn = kb$ for some integer $k$.

Now $\gcd(b,n)$ divides both $b$ and $n$ so we can divide both sides by $\gcd(b,n)$ to get

$m[\frac {n}{\gcd(b,n)}] = k[\frac b{\gcd(b,n)}]$

(*Note: even though the values written in the square brackets are written as fractions, they are, of course, integers and the denominators do divide the numerators*.)

Now as all are integers these means $[\frac{n}{\gcd(b,n)}]$ divides $k[\frac b{\gcd(b,n)}]$.  But $[\frac{n}{\gcd(b,n)}]$ and $[\frac b{\gcd(b,n)}]$ are relatively prime integers, we must have that $[\frac{n}{\gcd(b,n)}]$ divides $k$[*].

So we can divide both sides by $[\frac{n}{\gcd(b,n)}]$ to get

$m = [\frac k{[\frac{n}{\gcd(b,n)}]}][\frac{n}{\gcd(b,n)}]$

.... and that's that.  $[\frac k{[\frac{n}{\gcd(b,n)}]}]$ is an integer and so $m$ is a multiple of $[\frac{n}{\gcd(b,n)}]$.

.....

From that the proof follows straightforwardly:

$a^k\equiv 1$ if and only if $k$ is a multiple of $\lambda$.

So $(a^e)^f=a^{ef}\equiv 1$ if and only if $ef$ is a multiple of $\lambda$.

So as $ef$ is a multiple of $\lambda$, we just proved that that means $f$ must be a multiple of $\frac {\lambda}{\gcd(\lambda, e)}$.

That's it.

........

[*]  I hope you are familiar with this more basic number theory result:

> For integers $a,b,k$, if $b$ divides $ak$ but $\gcd(b,k)=1$ then $b$ divides $a$.

This result should be intuitively obvious as all the divisors of $b$ divide into $ak$ but *none* of the divisors have anything in common with $b$ (which is relatively prime to $a$) so all the divisors of $b$ must divide into $k$.

More formally: If $b = \prod p_i^{m_i}$ is the unique prime factorisation of $b$ and than as $\gcd(a,b) =1$ non of the $p_i^{m_i}$ divide $ak$. But as $b$ and $k$ are relatively prime no $p_i$ can divide $k$ so by Euclid's Lemma $p_i^{m_i}|a$.  So $b = \prod p_i^{m_i}|a$.

Comment: Ok I see now. So by dividing with the $\gcd(\lambda, e)$ on both sides we form the components of the $lcm(\lambda, e)$ and those parts are coprime. 1) Can it also be $f \mid m$? If we have $f \cdot a = m \cdot b$ and $gcd(a,b) = 1$ does that mean either $f \mid m$ or $a \mid m$?

2) I didn't understand how we get the formula for $l(a^e)$ mentioned in the last line of the quote.

Comment: What is the property when $a\cdot b \mid c \cdot e$ and $gcd(b, e) = 1$?

Comment: "Can it also be f∣m? If we have f⋅a=m⋅b and gcd(a,b)=1 does that mean either f∣m or a∣m?" It *ALWAYS* means $a|m$. And unless $b=1$ we will *never* have $f|m$.  See, $a$ and $b$ have no factors in common at all.  But we have $a|mb$ but as $a$ and $b$ have no factors in common $a$ must have *all* factors in common with $m$ and none in common with $b$.  So $a|m$.  Always.  And $b|f$.  Always.

Comment: `we will never have |` I am not clear why though.

Comment: Also what about the last line of the quoted formula? How is that derived from the previous? I think I am losing a step in the logic

Comment: $fa = mb$  So $a = \frac fm\cdot b$. But $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ so $b\not \mid a$ (***UNLESS** $b = 1$) so $\frac fm$ can not be an integer.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque: How is my post which is about asking something specific from a proof a duplicate?

Comment: @fleablood: Sorry for the basic question, a variable with the notation $b'$ does it have some specific meaning? I.e. what is the difference, if any, with declaring e.g. $x$ instead of $b'$?

Comment: @fleablood: nevermind, I worked through the proof, and I noticed that using $x$ and $y$ is not helpful at all. Notation matters....

Comment: @fleablood: "So $n$ is a multiple of $b' = \frac b{\gcd(b,m)}$" isn't $m$ a multiple of $b'$ as well by the same reasoning and proof? So what is the conclusion? Both $m$ and $n$ are multiple of $b'$?

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot! The only thing, that I am not clear is my previous comment. Looks like both $m$ and $n$ are multiples of $b'$? So we can also say that: "Or in other words $e=\frac{m\cdot \lambda}{f}$" as well instead of "Or in other words $f=\frac{m\cdot \lambda}{e}$"? So both $e$ and $f$ are multiple of $\lambda$? But we chose to work with $f$ for convenience?

Comment: @fleablood: Lemma 2 is Euclid's lemma. What are the names of Lemma 1 and 3? Is the property: $a \mid b \implies k\cdot a \mid k \cdot b$ mentioned somewhere with a specific name? Or it is just regular arithmetic rules?

Comment: Okay examples. $b = 475=3\times 5^3$ and $n=525=3\times 5^2\times 7$ and $m=1375=5^3\times 11$.  Now $mn$ is a multiple of $b$. Now $d_1 = \gcd(n,b)=75$.  And $d_2 = \gcd(m,b) = 125$.  Now $b_1' = \frac {b}{\gcd(n,b)} = \frac b{75} =5$ but $b_2' = \frac b{\gcd(m,b)} = \frac b{125} =3$.  As $nm = kb\implies n(m'd_2) = k(b_2'd_2)\implies $n=\frac k{m'}b_2'$ is a multiple of $b_2=\frac b{\gcd(m,b)}=3$ and also $nm = kb\implies (n'd_1)m= k(b_1'd_1)\implies $m=\frac k{n'}b_1'$ is a multiple of $b_1=\frac b{\gcd(n,b)}=5$.

Comment: I don't know the names.  They are basic.    $a|b \implies ka|kb$ is so basic it barely requires noting.

Comment: @fleablood: Thank you very much for the clear and very helpful answer! I got it! I have a last question for you. I have noted the $3$ lemma's you had written and was wondering how are they commonly known? E.g. what you had noted as Lemma 1, I found it in my book as a corollary statement, not a lemma and I didn't make the proper connection with the specific proof in the form that it was presented. So is the naming of these properties standard or not? E.g. is Lemma 2 universally considered Euclid's lemma? Is lemma 1 universally considered as what you explained?

Comment: @fleablood: by the way I am still not sure how we get the last part of the formula: $$l(a^e) = \frac{l(a)}{\gcd(e,\lambda)}$$. I mean $l(a)$ is $\lambda$ so where is the multiple?